# Get 0 values on count for a interval of time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've been looking for answers on SO but I didn't solved my problem. I've two tables, `profiles` and `profiles_visitors` that stores the visitors of the first.

I want to know how many visitors the user had in the last 15 days, so I've write this:

```
SELECT COUNT(pv.id) AS `count`, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.created_at)) AS `date`
FROM profiles p
LEFT JOIN profiles_visitors pv ON pv.profiles_id=p.id
WHERE p.users_id='50' AND pv.created_at >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 day)
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(pv.created_at))
```

Result of the query:

```
+-------+-------------------+
| count | date              |
+-------+-------------------+
| 2     | 2012-10-26        |
+-------+-------------------+
| 3     | 2012-10-29        |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Desired results:

```
+-------+-------------------+
| count | date              |
+-------+-------------------+
| 0     | 2012-10-15        |
+-------+-------------------+
.......... 0s here ..........
+-------+-------------------+
| 0     | 2012-10-25        |
+-------+-------------------+
| 2     | 2012-10-26        |
+-------+-------------------+
| 0     | 2012-10-27        |
+-------+-------------------+
| 0     | 2012-10-28        |
+-------+-------------------+
| 3     | 2012-10-29        |
+-------+-------------------+
| 0     | 2012-10-30        |
+-------+-------------------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the count of `profiles` rows and not the `profile_vistors` (because if there is no visit, then there is no row in the profile_vistors table) as:

```
 SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS 'count'
```

Also, if you want, you may use `DATEDIFF` function as :

```
    DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), pv.created_at) <=15
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me 0 results. The problem is where there is NO visit, so there is no row it can return.

Comment: @udexter: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: I've tried and the SELECT gives me the same results. Using your DATEDIFF gives me 0 results. :(

Comment: @udexter: Did you try with `COUNT(p.id)`?